# Speed up file loading express

Tags: node.js, express

I sometimes upload files to my website (usually mp4 files, so we'll call them videos for now), but when I then get the URL for them, the video doesn't load swiftly at all.

- My website is hosted on my pi at home
- I'm using express.js

  - I'm `app.use()`ing the [`compression`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression) package.
- [speedtest.net](https://speedtest.net) returns 38.44 Mb/s down and 13.91 Mb/s up

[Here's an example video.](https://lieuweberg.com/files/nnnjy2.mp4) The video is 39Mb in size.

Would anyone know how I would get much faster loading speeds? I'm 100% sure the problem is server (pi) sided.